# Regular expression to match url patterns

Tags: php, regex

I want to create a function which would validate possible url patterns in my CMS. The possible patterns:

```
9-naberanie-cistej-hmoty
demonize-p18
maximizing-your-prohormone-cycle-34
```

1. link pattern

   - CATEGORY_ID-CATEGORY_URL
2. link pattern

   - PRODUCT_URL-pPRODUCT_ID
3. link pattern

   - ARTICLE_URL-ARTICLE_ID

Is it possible to validate it via regular expression ? I was thinking about exploding the stuff but it would take more steps if there is regexp for this which I could use it would b e great. I am not familiar with regexp so thanks for any help

Code:

```
$category = "9-naberanie-cistej-hmoty";
preg_match("([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z-]+)", $category);
```

When I run this code I get

> Message: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '-'

Comment: Certainly that is possible. But please note that SO is _not_ a free coding service. We are here to help you _with your own code_. You are not here to do your work for you. So start out yourself, implement what you need. Then, if you run into an issue you cannot solve or understand yourself in your own code, _then_ is the time to come here and ask by posting your code and pointing out the issue in a precise and specific manner.

Comment: well could you at least provide me with link where I can find some patterns and how to start?

Comment: There are endless tutorials about regular expressions to be found on google.

Comment: well I figured something out. I have working regex ([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z-]+) but if I put this as pattern to preg_replace I get unknown modifier '-' how can I fix this

Comment: Please add such additional details into the question itself, do not post them in comments. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it._

Comment: And please post the whole php row, not just the pattern.

Comment: Please read the documentation of the functions you use. You forgot to enclose your pattern into bounding characters. It should be something like `preg_match('|([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z-]+)|', $category);`. (note the additional `|` characters enclosing the pattern)

Comment: Thanks got all 3 regex wasnt that hard after all I posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, great that you yourself gave a pretty good answer after you started thinking about your question!

I only made some small modifications. Not to answer your question, YOU DID, but to point out that you should anchor your expressions to the start and end of the subjects by adding a preceding `^` and a trailing `$`...

Also a closing php tag rarely is a good idea...

```
<?php
$category = "9-naberanie-cistej-hmoty";
$product  = "demonize-p18";
$article  = "maximizing-your-prohormone-cycle-34";

preg_match('/^([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z-]+)$/', $category, $matches);
preg_match('/^([A-Za-z-]+)-p([0-9]+)$/', $product, $matches);
preg_match('/^([A-Za-z-]+)-([0-9]+)$/', $article, $matches);
```

Comment: thanks, edited it in my code. well it was just a snip from my code so wanted to make just example. but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to arkascha I worked on the answer :)

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$category = "9-naberanie-cistej-hmoty";
$product  = "demonize-p18";
$article  = "maximizing-your-prohormone-cycle-34";

preg_match("/([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z-]+)/", $category, $matches);
preg_match("/([A-Za-z-]+)-p([0-9]+)/", $product, $matches);
preg_match("/([A-Za-z-]+)-([0-9]+)/", $article, $matches);
?>
```